# Where is ISolrConnection being registered for SolrNet Dependency Injection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, solr, solrnet

I have an MVC web app where I am setting up a custom IoC container with CastleWindsor.

The app has some existing code in Global.asax ApplicationStart that resolves a list of ISolrConnections using:-

```
DependencyResolver.Current.GetServices<ISolrConnection>();
```

Given that I am in ApplicationStart, I wasn't expected anything to be registered here, or even for the DependencyResolver to be set to anything...
However it does resolve successfully.

I was wondering where ISolrConnection (and for that fact, any other types) are registered, so I can move this to my own container instead?

Note: The issue I am having is that when I switch to my DependencyResolver with my custom container, ISolrConnection can no longer be resolved.
The application makes use of a couple of Solr DLLs, including SolrNet, Castle.Facilities.SolrNetIntegration, etc. I didn't add these to the project, but suspect this is where the types are being registered.

Comment: Tried a solution-wide search for `ISolrConnection`? :)

Comment: Yep, did that... nothing is registering it in my code.

Comment: It may actually be that GetServices is called, not GetService.....so an empty collection is returned, not a null. In which case...nothing to see here.

Comment: https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Castle.Facilities.SolrNetIntegration/SolrNetFacility.cs#L80-L81